# Is there a library for UNSIGNED integers with 256 or 512 bits for .Net?

Tags: c#, integer, unsigned

I know there is Bigmath, but those ints are signed. Is there a lib for unsigned integers with 256 or 512 bits in .net? (Not unlimited like BigInt...)

Comment: What operations would you be looking to perform on these integers?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Multiplication, addition, bitshift, modulo, subtraction, division

Comment: not that I know of, now, if you were asking how to write one... Why do you need large numbers but don't want to use `BigInt`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling `UInt256` I easily found https://github.com/pmlyon/BitSharp/blob/master/BitSharp.Common/UInt256.cs.

Comment: Hmm, I googled it and somehow missed that. Thanks for actually answering instead of criticizing :)

Comment: @pixartist I think I searched the exact phrase `"struct UInt256"` in combination with `C#` or `.cs` or similar.